# xpath and operator always returning true

Tags: xpath

```
"//a[contains(@data-testid,'actionLink')] | //a[contains(@aria-pressed,'false')]"
```

this returns 15

```
"//a[contains(@data-testid,'actionLink')] or //a[contains(@aria-pressed,'false')]"
```

this returns true

But I want to use AND operator.

```
"//a[contains(@data-testid,'actionLink')] and //a[contains(@aria-pressed,'false')]"
```

returns true but I need integer value.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31473713/12914378) answer and is and. how can I get integer value?

HTML code:

```
<a aria-pressed="false" class=" _6a-y _3l2t  _18vj" data-testid="UFI2ReactionLink" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1"><i alt="" class="_6rk2 img sp_gFJy5OP1MUR sx_ee42f4"></i>Like</a>
```

Comment: Why do you want an integer value? What does `15` represent?

Comment: I will click random links and I found the solution. //a[@role='button' and @aria-pressed='false']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clear things up `|` isn't or, it's union and returns a resultset.
You're combining your results sets for `"//a[contains(@data-testid,'actionLink')]` with the result set for `//a[contains(@aria-pressed,'false')]"`.

The reason you're getting a boolean result is because that's how boolean operators work(they give you a boolean response to two conditions, for node lists it'll be true for non-empty and false for empty lists).

If you want to get the nodes like you appear to be wanting to do you have to write your query in such a way that you're matching `a` tags where the filter contains your combined comparison:

```
"//a[contains(@data-testid,'actionLink') and contains(@aria-pressed,'false')]"
```

Comment: Note also, the analogy with the `|` (union) operator would be to use the `intersect` operator, which forms the intersection of two node-sets. This requires XPath 2.0 or later. The expression `//x[condition-1] intersect //x[condition-2]` gives the same result as the expression `//x[condition-1 and condition-2]`. Basic boolean algebra and set theory here...